# Define the max length of a string in a StructField in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to define the metadata in PySpark. Some of the columns have a max length for a string type. I noticed  in the [documenation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html) there is the type **VarcharType**. However, it does not exist in **pyspark.sql.types**:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
my_schema = StructType([
    StructField("POSTAL_CODE", VarcharType(4))
    , StructField("CITY", VarcharType(20))
])
```

```
NameError: name 'VarcharType' is not defined
```

Is it possible to have it? If not possible, how can I achieve the result?

Comment: Could you provide your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the Spark official document, which is the link you post in the question, it mentioned that `VarcharType - Note: this type can only be used in table schema, not functions/operators.` As you are using the Pyspark API to create your schema, there is no `VarcharType` supported (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/data_types.html).

To achieve your goal, if you keep using the Pyspark API to create dataframe schema, then you should change to `StringType()`, otherwise you need to create table through sql statement.

Comment: Hello Jonathan, my excuses. Indeed, I badly read. thanks you